# Design issue: Need some tips on how to structure my class inheritance to avoid duplication of code

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, merge

Let's assume I have some logic implemented in a class called "Geometry".
My class "Line" inherits from Geometry and implements some functionality to draw a line in 2d and my other class "Circle" inherits again from Geometry and draws circles in 2d.
Now I'm creating another class Geometry3d : Geometry which adds features on top of Geometry in effect forcing all inherited classes to operate in 3d space. And here I'm running into this problem - I'd like to reuse all my code from Line and Circle classes, but have them inherit from the Geometry3d class as well, turning them into Line3d and Circle3d classes. Is this achievable without duplicating code?

For example how do I accomplish this:

```
var myCircle2d = new Circle(); // this would be Geometry : Circle
var myCircle3d = new Circle3d(); // this would be Geometry : Geometry3d: Circle: Circle3d
```

Note that the code in the Circle class is the same and the Circle3d class would be an empty container

Is there a design pattern to make it possible to inject a parent like that?

Comment: Starting it off with a side note, your parent class should probably be named `Shape`. `Geometry` is far too broad and with a name like that it will have far too many responsibilities. That said, I would do `Shape`, `Shape: Shape2D`, and `Shape:Shape3D`. Better yet, generalize dimensionality and just do `Shape`, `Shape : Sphere`, and `Shape: Circle`

Comment: Right, I have no problems doing that. The point here is that the code inside the Circle and Sphere classes is exactly the same in my case. The different behavior is extracted and lives inside the Shape3d class. So I can do Shape : Circle and I can also do Shape : Shape3d: Sphere and copy/paste all my code from Circle into my Sphere class ... not exactly a best practice though

Comment: And note that inheritance is only one of many ways to reuse code.  You could, for instance, have Circle and Circle3d implement a common interface and operate over instances of either one in methods declared on other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have inheritance from multiple base classes in C#. You can usually solve this with composition. You could make Geometry3D contain the Geometry as a member variable as follows:

```
class GenericGeometry3D<T> : Geometry3D where T : Geometry{
    T InnerGeometry;
    public GenericGeometry3D(T innerGeometry){
        InnerGeometry = innerGeometry;
    }

    //implement functionality of Geometry by redirecting to the inner geometry
    //you can auto generate these methods in VS by selecting 'Implement through'
    public void MethodInGeometry(){
       InnerGeometry.MethodInGeometry();
    }
    //...

    //extra functionality provided by Geometry3D
    //...
}
```

You will then automatically have `GenericGeometry3D<Circle>` and `GenericGeometry3D<Line>` classes. I'm not sure if this pattern has a name. It is a bit similar to the decorator pattern.

You can then create Circle3D as follows:

```
class Circle3D : GenericGeometry3D<Circle>{
  public Circle3D(...) : base (new Circle(...)) { }
}
```